# How to add images with text prior to the image, and the images follow same order as in the code

Tags: graphics

I have some graphs showing my result and I want to add images in a particular order and some explanatory text prior to the image. Here is the code that I am having, but the images show in a strange order, because they do not follow linearity expressed in the code.

```
This is some text and I want the images to follow each other in the same order as represented in this code. 

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{img1.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}


If the image does not fit in the page, then it should continue to the next page, but the order is important.

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{img.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}


Text for figure 3

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{img2.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am using the IEEE template for journal, so maybe that has also something to do with it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you do not want that figures can float simply do not use environment figure.

Comment: As Mensch says, `\includegraphic` is enough. However, if for some reason you need to use `figure`, you can add `\usepackage{float}` in your preamble, then `\begin{figure}[H]`.

Comment: @Iacobus1983 I only wanted figure for captions, is there any without having to use \begin{.... ?

Comment: @Sachihiro as said, `\usepackage{float}` in your preamble, then `\begin{figure}[H]`, should do. Or else, have a look to `\captionof` command of `caption` package.

Comment: Use `[H]` or avoid floats  will leave ugly gaps when the images "almost"  fit in he page. The figure floats  exist  to avoid that. The issue that it can move too far from  text about that figure is the reason why there are captions and labels: to  make cross-references . Do not type `Text for figure 3` but `Text for figure \ref{fig:mesh3} in \pageref{fig:mesh3}`  (obviously,  to point to `\label{fig:mesh3}` not to `fig:mesh1`,  your duplicated labels have no sense!) and then the text always will point to the right figure number and page.